# How to print a function output to a new file?

Tags: printing, emacs, dired

I'm simply trying to export the filenames of *marked* files from a Dired buffer to a new text file.

Looking at the manual, I found the function `(dired-get-marked-files)`.

In a Dired buffer, after marking three files for test purposes, evaluating:
`(dired-get-marked-files 'verbatim nil nil nil t)`
prints:
`("vid_1.mp4" "vid_2.mp4" "vid_3.mp4")`.

So far so good, but my lack of elisp knowledge put me at a stop now. Basically I would like to have those three filenames on each line in a new text file `fileslist.txt` in the same directory like this:

```
file 'vid_1.mp4'
file 'vid_2.mp4'
file 'vid_3.mp4'
```

I tried something like below and calling it from the Dired buffer but it doesn't work.

```lisp
(defun my/test-dired ()
  "fileslist.txt creation."
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-file "fileslist.txt" (dired-get-marked-files 'verbatim nil nil nil t)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun write-marked-file-names-to-file ()
  "Write names of marked files to file `fileslist.txt'."
  (interactive)
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
    (error "You must be in Dired or a mode derived from it to use this command"))
  (let ((files  (dired-get-marked-files 'verbatim nil nil nil t)))
    (with-temp-file "fileslist.txt"
      (dolist (file  files)
        (princ (concat "file '" file "'\n") (current-buffer))))))
```

Comment: Thank you @Drew. `(diredp-ensure-mode)` returns `Symbol’s function definition is void: diredp-ensure-mode`, commenting it out works. Last thing, how would I do to append the word "file" before each filename being quoted by single quotes? Just like in my example above (`file 'vid_1.mp4'`).

Comment: Oops. I replaced `diredp-ensure-mode` by its definition (in [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus)).

Comment: Updated example to wrap file names with `file '`...`'`.

Comment: Everything works. Thank you for your help. I'm also happy because I understand each lines you added and what it does exactly, so I feel like I learnt some elisp too.

Comment: That's why I posted it - thinking it might be close enough to what you tried to teach a few things by the few differences.